# How can I automate chaining a series of ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Look at the lower part of my function: I want to repeat  `info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, function(next) {` couple of times. Is there a smarter way than one presented below (maybe some kind of loop)? I've been thinking whole day and I can't devise anything.

```
 function info(link, callback) {
        $.getJSON(link, function(json) {
            $.each(json.data.children, function(i, things) {
                $("#threadlist").append('<img src="' + things.data.url + '">');
            });
            callback(json.data.after);
        });
    }
    var url_first = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?jsonp=?";
    var url_part1 = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?after=";
    var url_part2 = "&jsonp=?";

    info(url_first, function(next) {
        info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, function(next) {
            info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, function(next) {
                info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, function(next) {
                    info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, function(next) {

                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdUBD/1/

Comment: Here is a cleaned-up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdUBD/2/ Note, slower computers may experience issues loading these pages.

Comment: @JaredFarrish and faster computers won't notice a difference in the synchronicity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/JwAbK/

Comment: So simple it is, so dumb i am that I haven't came across it by myself. Thanks.

Comment: jQury deferred object are very usefull and power : http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider processing them recursively.

```
function processRequest( request)
{
      $.getJSON(request,function(json) {
          // process json
          if (json.data.after) {
             processRequest( "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?after="
                                 + json.data.after 
                                 + "&jsonp=?" );
          }
      });
}

processRequest("http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?jsonp=?");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it seems that all you want to do is call a function recursively, up to a certain number of times. Here is sample code that does exactly that:

```
function testFunction(number, callback) {
    document.writeln("testFunction() called with number = " + number + "<br />");
    callback(number + 1);
}

var CallCount = 0;
testFunction(1, function(next) {
    CallCount++;
    document.writeln("callback called next = " + next + "<br />");

    if(CallCount == 5) {
        document.writeln("callback called 5 times, don't call it again");
    } else {
        testFunction(next, arguments.callee);
    }
});
```

That code outputs the following:

```
testFunction() called with number = 1
callback called next = 2
testFunction() called with number = 2
callback called next = 3
testFunction() called with number = 3
callback called next = 4
testFunction() called with number = 4
callback called next = 5
testFunction() called with number = 5
callback called next = 6
callback called 5 times, don't call it again
```

You can try it out at jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/NQya6/

Applying this to your code you get:

```
var DebugCount = 0;
function EmulateGetJson(link, callback) {
    DebugCount++;
    callback({
        data: {
            children: [
                { data : { url: "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png?" + DebugCount, next: "next" } }
            ]
        }
    });
}

 function info(link, callback) {
    //$.getJSON(link, function(json) {
    EmulateGetJson(link, function(json) {
        $.each(json.data.children, function(i, things) {
            $("#threadlist").append('<img src="' + things.data.url + '">');
        });
        callback(json.data.after);
    });
}

var url_first = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?jsonp=?";
var url_part1 = "http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/.json?after=";
var url_part2 = "&jsonp=?";

var CallCount = 0;
var TargetCallCount = 5;
info(url_first, function(next) {
    CallCount++;

    if(CallCount != TargetCallCount) {
        info(url_part1 + next + url_part2, arguments.callee);
    }
});
```

The jsFiddle for this can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/uY8Kj/

I emulated the call to `$.getJSON` in JavaScript code in order to provide a complete example. I appended a number to the end of the sample image URL to illustrate that a different URL was being returned each time.

`arguments.callee` refers to the current function, in this case the function you are passing as the callback to `info()` this is the key to the recursion.